# Subversion Edge installing certificate on Windows deployment

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl, certificate, https, svn

I'm trying to get HTTPS to work on a new Collab.net Subversion Edge server deployed on a Windows environment. It currently serves the site in HTTPS but is using the default self-signed cert.

I located a cert folder in C:\csvn\data\certs. After replacing the following certs with my Wildcard ones (renamed mine to match the existing names). I restarted the CollabNet Subversion Server service (Description says Apache), then rebooted the machine. The site is still utilizing the svnedge.collab.net cert.

- cloud_services_root_ca.crt
- svnedge.crt

The documentation is lacking on how to install a cert. It mentions the self-signed cert and purchasing one, but not how to install it.

What am I doing wrong and/or where should I be putting my certs?
Also, I did not touch the svnedge.key. Should I be generating a new one of those?

Comment: There is no lack of documentation : [random example](http://tud.at/programm/apache-ssl-win32-howto.php3).

Comment: @harrymc That documentation doesn't help with this problem.

Comment: [Blog posting](https://pawan6782.wordpress.com/2015/08/20/collabnet-edge-subversion/) dealing with configuring Subversion Edge wrapper with a proper certificate.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and yes the documentation for this is crap. The CollabNet Subversion Server service that runs the underlying Apache instance stores the certificates here:

[CSVN_HOME]/data/conf/

I put my wildcard ssl (server.crt, server.key and server.ca) in this location (replace existing) then restarted the CollabNet Subversion Server service.

Answer (score 0):

How to Update an Expired Subversion Edge Server Security Certificate

1. Stop both CollaNet SVN Edge and CollabNet SVN Server services
2. The default self-signed svnedge.jks (JKS File type) and svnedge-ssl config file are in C:\csvn\appserver\etc
3. Create new svnedge.jks for your server (use full server CN)
4. Rename the expired svnedge.jks to svnedge.jks.bak and save a backup copy of the svnedge-ssl file
5. Edit the svnedge-ssl file to update default ssl port to "4434" -
6. Deploy the new svnedge.jks to C:\csvn\appserver\etc
7. Restart both services